# Windows app using Wine?

Tags: wine

Can I run windows file from my corrupted windows harddrive using mount to Linux and run wine application, because I want to run some program from corrupted hard disk to get some program data?

Comment: I would venture a short answer here: No.

Comment: Thanks for answer,  so I need do some thing other.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a Windows program with Wine you must first install it in Wine, and in order to do that you need  to locate the program's installation file. Usually it's an .exe file. Alternatively you can install some Windows apps in Ubuntu, for example Google Chrome web browser has a .deb file which can be downloaded from the Google Chrome website and installed in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` Then launch Chrome and recover your Gmail account. You can also try using Google Chrome on your phone.

If that doesn't work Google launched a specific help forum for Google Accounts: https://support.google.com/accounts/community and please read the answers to [How do I recover my Google account (or Gmail) password or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52706/).

Comment: Basically, I cannot recover my Gmailnin new device due to authenticator lost, so I try that If I can access my Windows' Chrome so I can recover my account.

Comment: @Mohsin You've got a phone, right so try it in Google Chrome on your phone and see if it lets you do anything to recover your Gmail account. And please read the update to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I try it, but after phone verification its want recovery email verification, but I cannot access to recovery email too

Comment: @Mohsin See if you can find anything on your phone in your phone's Gmail app. btw the Gmail app for phones requires 2-factor authentication since about 2 month's ago which makes account recovery much easier because you can verify your identity with 2fa.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how corrupted your hard disk is. Also, not all windows application work equally well in Wine. You can find more about specific applications on the [application database](https://appdb.winehq.org/) for Wine.

There's really nothing more we can say here. You should try it out yourself.

Comment: I basically need to run chrome to recover my Gmail account from Windows HDD that won't simply boot.

Comment: You can install Chrome in Ubuntu. I still don't get it.